# Poisson Regression to estimate mortality

Tags: r, biostatistics, poisson-regression, epidemiology

I am trying to estimate the rate of death for patients with epilepsy over a period of 13 years. I have the number of people known epileptics who died and all causes of death. This is the way I have done it.

```
poisson.model.rate <- glm(death.associated.with.epilepsy~ year + 
    offset(logpop), family = poisson(link = "log"), data = epi)
summary(epi)
#display summary
summary(poisson.model.rate)
```

Does this look right ?

Comment: If logpop is log of the population from which the rate should be derived, yes it looks ok